# Mysql Error could not enter data. No database selected

Tags: php, mysql

This is my Php file code. When i insert the data using input fields in HTML i get the Error could not enter data. No database selected.

```
$dbhost="localhost";

$dbuser="root";

$dbpass="";

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn ) {

die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO sale '.
'(Name, Contact, Email, Property_type, Price, Location) '.
'VALUES ( "$a", "$b", "$c", "$d", "$e", "$f" )';

mysql_select_db('gharghar_gharastee');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ) {

die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());

}

echo "Entered data successfully\n";

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: What happens if you run query direct database?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(Name, Contact, Email, Property_type, Price, Location) '. VALUES ( "oman", "' at line 3

Comment: So theres the problem your query got issue could you please print full query here that you tried to run on db.

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the latest version of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the connection to your db

```
// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('gharghar_gharastee', $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use gharghar_gharastee : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

And I suggest you use PDO instead of mysql_connect - for security reasons and it has be depreciated in the newer version of php

Comment: Can't use foo : Access denied for user 'gharghar_ghar'@'localhost' to database 'gharghar_gharastee'

Comment: And that the user has permissions set to access the database

Comment: #1044 - Access denied for user 'ghargharastee'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Answer (score -1):

You must use mysql SQL like this.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO sale '.
'(Name, Contact, Email, Property_type, Price, Location) '.
"VALUES ( '$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e', '$f' )";
```

Comment: Nothing would happened by applying this.

Comment: This isn't the problem ;)